# Get macro to ignore empty cells in a range but copy those with data

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a very simple macro that is copying data from a range of cells to the Clipboard and the macro is called from a button on a different worksheet to the one from on where the macro runs. The code for the macro was suggested by Tim Williams for me on a different thread/question and I am creating a new thread/question as it is a new question (I hope this is the correct way of doing it on Stackoverflow).

The worksheet that the macro copies data from is called "FinalData" and it is populated by various formulas which pulls data from other worksheets into the one worksheet

I need a way of telling the macro to look at the cells in the specified range and only copy any data from formulas in the cells in which the formulas have returned data but skip the cells with formulas that do not return any results (so when you are looking at the worksheet the cell looks empty even though it is not). The data in cells within the range may change depending on what a user (me) may enter on other worksheets before running the macro.

Here is an example of how the range is copied and what the macro returns at the moment:

```
B1 = Red
B2 = Yellow

B4 = Green


B7 = Gray
```

Notice that the macro includes the "blank Cells"

This is how I actually need the Macro to copy and return the data:

```
B1 =Red
B2 = Yellow
B4 = Green
B7 = Gray
```

The Macro would ignore cells where the formula in the cell has not returned data (so to look at the worksheet these cells would look blank) and does not copy blank cells.

This is my Macro at the moment:

```
Sub CopyFinalData()
'
' Copies the specified range to the Clipboard

Sheets("html_For_eBay").Range("B1:B324").Copy

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: The question to which you allude is nothing to do me.

Comment: @Kenny did you try my coe below ?

Comment: Hi Shai Yes I did and it gave a run-time error. I have replied to you post to explain.

Comment: cyboashu - why have you marked this as a duplicate question. The other question you claim is the same as mine is completely different with different needs and requirements by the poster. It is clearly different to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Sub CopyFinalData()
'
Dim lRow As Long
Dim c As Range

' start copying from first row
lRow = 1
For Each c In Sheets("html_For_eBay").Range("B1:B324").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Len(c) <> 0 Then
        ' modify "Sheet2" according to your sheet name, as well as Column B
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, "B").Value = c.Value
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This creates a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error. When I click on Debug the line of code below is highlighted in yellow... Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, "B").Value = c.Value

Comment: @Kenny where do you want to copy this to ? which sheet ? in my code I used for tests only `"Sheet2"` , you need to modify to your desried sheet name and column

Comment: It should be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: to do what ? just remain there ? where is it destinated to be pasted ?

Comment: The clipboard is Ctrl+V pasted into a html document between the <p> & </p> tags.

Comment: @Kenny you can use a workaround, copy it into another sheet `("Sheet2")`, where it will be pasted without empty cells, and then just copy it from "Sheet2"

Comment: Do you mean using your code because it still give a run-time error

Comment: @Kenny what are the other sheet names you have in your current workbook ?

Comment: There are 14 other worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: Based on your suggestions I have been able to record a macro which does as you suggest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, if I helped upvote